# C++ std: Making a polynomial class, how to suppress all 0 coefficients that the user inputs?

Tags: c++

Now I have my Polynomial class (almost done) with integer coefficients.
One of the member functions in this class displays the polynomial as:
if the user inputs:
1, -2, 0, 4
then the function prints it as "p(x)=1+-2x+0x^2+4x^3"
which is not expected because I want to eliminate the 0x^2 term since it has a 0 coefficient..
it's supposed to be: "p(x)=1+-2x+4x^3" instead.

Now my "print" member function is here:

```
void Polynomial::print() const
{
    //prints out the polynomial in the simplest form

    string plus;//plus sign in front of every element except the first element
    plus="+";
    int k=0;//same as k
    cout<<coefficient[0];
    for(int i=1;i<coefficient.size();i++)
    {
        if(coefficient[i]==-12345)
            break;//where -12345 is the key to enter to stop inputting 
        cout<<plus<<coefficient[i]<<"x";

        if(coefficient[i]!=-12345)
        {
            k++;
        }
        if(k>1)
        {
            cout<<"^"<<k;
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
```

what else should I add to eliminate the 0 coefficient ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use an "if" statement.  And `-12345` as a magic sequence to stop?  Ouch!

Comment: I think you should handle negative coeffs as well. The form `1+-2x` is not very pleasant to the eye.

Comment: thanks; @John, how do I write this if statement? I've been thinking for hours...

Comment: @roshinichi Seriously? How about `if (coefficient[i] != 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to be something like the following:

```
void Polynomial::print() const {
    // Ignore initial pluses, set to "+" when first term is output.

    string plus = "";

    if (coefficient[0] != 0) {
        // Output initial x^0 coefficient.

        cout << coefficient[0];

        // Ensure future positives have sign.

        plus = "+";
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < coefficient.size(); i++) {
        // Only for non-zero coefficients.

        if (coefficient[i] != 0) {
            // Only output + for positives.

            if (coefficient[i] > 0) {
                cout << plus;

            // Output coefficient and x.

            cout << coefficient[i] << "x";

            // Output exponent if 2 or more.

            if (i > 1)
                cout << "^" << i;

            // Ensure future positives have sign.

            plus = "+";
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly ignores zero terms *and* gets rid of the annoying `+-` sequences where you just need `-`, such as turning:

```
x+-3x^2
```

into:

```
x-3x^2
```

It also ensures you don't print a leading `+` on the first term output.